# Dockerfile with env file

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

how to use .env in Dockerfile if i dont push the .env file on my repository ? 
because i want to use dockerfile to work with jenkins on my repository

my dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["npm", "run" , 'dev']
```

i am very new about this, and here i am trying to deploy my nodejs api with docker and integration with jenkins for Continues deployment ,  i have follow some articles so i tried to using dockerfile and jenkisfile on my linux server

my .env is something like this , for mongod db

```
DB_USERNAME=for_USERNAME_DB
DB_PASSWORD=for_PASSWORD_DB
DB_NAME=for_DATABASE_NAME
```

my example Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t mygithub/express-api:latest'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker run mygithub/express-api:latest npm test'
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'docker push mygithub/express-api:latest'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        failure {
            echo 'build is broken. notify team!'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you want to have the jenkins server to run integration tests otherwise you shouldn't need the secrets there. In our setup, we generate a new set of credentials to run the tests and finally throw away the instances once the integration tests are done. In order to do this, we generate a `.env` every time.

Comment: so we should create private repo ?

Comment: I don't think you need it. Just add the `.env` file in `.gitignore` and create it on the fly when you need it.

Comment: so it will be ok on my express which need .env when i run jenkins and dockerfile without .env on github ? because i want integration it everytime i push to master, my api server on vps also update that i set on my jenkins server

Comment: on what DB the integration tests are going to run? if you plan to run the integration tests on a fresh new DB then you can create your own `.env` file on the fly. On the other hand, if you plan to have jenkins start the application once the commits have been done, the situation changes and you need store the .env file directly on the server. Anyway, in either case you don't want to store the .env file (or any hardcoded password) on a git repo

Comment: i still confused can u explain more step by step should i do ? because i want to my express server run on ubuntu server , and using jenkins and docker, but i still get confused, been learn and read a lot articles for a week but still not understand how to

Comment: my step is first, git clone my repo on my ubuntu server,  and run jenkins with pipeline to build dockerfile , then , will it run on my server ? and if i push a change to that branch , will it update also on my server ?

Comment: so you would like to have the jenkins to simply start the docker-compose. Not for testing or anything else. Well, in this case create your `.env` file on the server and copy it during the build so that the docker-compose can use it. Anyway this is a test environment, correct?

Comment: can you open chat ? here

Comment: apparently not... I don't have the possibility to create a chat here

Comment: i want to test my express js and deploy it with jenkins and docker on my ubuntu server, so on my express js  i have uri for mongodb which has process.env for my database name, password, and username,

Comment: look at my jenkinsfile on my question above, i just update

Comment: ok, it looks like that the only location where you might need to have a `.env` is in the Test stage. The question now is: against what DB are you running these tests? Probably not against production, so I'd create a .env file on the jenkins server and I'd copy it in the build. In other words, I'd add a `sh 'cp $secret_location/.env .env'` before the tests are going to execute. where $secret_location is the folder where I've created the file

Comment: can u give the answer on my question ? hmm, did u see my jenkinsfile above, is that correct ??

Comment: Just to be clear, this is an option. A better option if you're using a cloud provider would be to use the secret stores (e.g. AWS Secrets)

Comment: how about gcp ??

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets

Comment: i really dont understand about to do that :( -__-

Comment: I'm sorry I added the wrong link. The idea would be that you'll have your Jenkins pulling the required secrets for your environment when needed without storing them locally

Comment: thx for your some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create .env or env_file_name at run time by using a script in Jenkins or Configuration tool with your environment values as below.

```
DB_USERNAME=for_USERNAME_DB
DB_PASSWORD=for_PASSWORD_DB
DB_NAME=for_DATABASE_NAME
```

In Jenkins use `--env-file` option while running the container to pass the environment variable inside the container for application. In this way you are not showing your environment variable in Dockerfile.

```
stage('Test') 
{
  steps 
  {
    sh 'docker run --env-file=env_file_name mygithub/express-api:latest npm test'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily an **architectural decision**. The technical implementation depends on it.

The question you can ask is:

> Who is the owner of the environment variables?

The owner is someone that administrates the environment (eg knows the db passwords of that environment,...)

Once you know who owns the ENVs you have to decide how s/he can change them => **technical decisions**.

1. You could make him/her commit the values to your git repo but you should not, as you would make everyone with read access to your repo, owner of your environments in terms of permissions)
2. You could add the env variables in the build step of your CI, if you have just one environment you build for.
3. You could add the env variables in the test / deploy steps of your CI

Most of the time 3. makes sense. @Mahattam gave an example how to add your .env file with `docker run --env-file ...`. The .env file can be a secret in your CI the owner has access to with his CI user.
You can also `docker run --mount ...` an .env file that is saved on the server you deploy your app to. The owner would have write access to that file on that host.

Multiple possibilities...as soon as you decided the ownership it becomes easier to decide the technical aspects for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't push the .env file, you can use ENV Dockerfile's instruction. Like:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

COPY ./ ./

ENV DB_USERNAME=for_USERNAME_DB
ENV DB_PASSWORD=for_PASSWORD_DB
ENV DB_NAME=for_DATABASE_NAME

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["npm", "run" , 'dev']
```

That's should work.

Comment: i will push my Dockerfile on my repo, if i do that on dockerfile, everyone would see my env is :(, i just want to hide them

Comment: You don't need necessary push the file with the informations writed into Dockerfile. You can push the model and change default values to right values into your environment.

Comment: What do you win by writing the ENV variables into the dockerfile? You can override the ENVs later in both cases (.env or dockerfile) I guess.